# facebook page feed page.php?id= returning 404

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've been using this url for feed data for quite some time, this morning it was reported broken.  I can't seem to find any information on this changing recently.

Is this still a valid feed url?

https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id={id}&format=json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not a valid feed url. The JSON feed have been deprecated. As explained at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Comment: wow, I thought I looked there.  Oh well, this is the right answer.  Thanks